# Only specific lambdas or arguments should be inline while creating inline function in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

While using `inline` functions, kotlin will inlined all things. Like function and arguments or lambdas which passed in function.
Example:

```
inline fun <T> myFun(getUserName: () -> String, getUserMobile: () -> String): T {
    // ...
}
```

Here in above example, `getUserName()` and `getUserMobile()` both will be inlined because we declare `myFun` as **inline** function.

As per kotlin doc:

> The inline modifier affects both the function itself and the lambdas
>   passed to it: all of those will be inlined into the call site.

Question is:

Can we declare the function which has **inline** and **non-inline** arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes we need some lambdas or arguments to be inlined and no need to other lambdas or arguments work as inline.

To avoid them as inlined we can use [`noinline`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#noinline) modifier.

Example:

```
inline fun <T> myFun(getUserName: () -> String, noinline getUserMobile: () -> String): T {
    // ...
}
```

As per Kotlin doc:

> Inlinable lambdas can only be called inside the inline functions or
>   passed as inlinable arguments, but noinline ones can be manipulated in
>   any way we like: stored in fields, passed around etc.

Check out more about Inline Functions:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#inline-functions